# I am getting an error in saying() method not able to compile?

Tags: java, methods

Here is my code :where i am getting error in this method

```
public void saying(){
        System.out.println("Your first gf was %s", getName());
    }
```

.....

not able to use getName()...as it asking to change the return type to Object[] which in return becomes not compatible to Scanner Object Input Type as have to enter String Value....here  String temp = input.nextLine();

```
public class UsingManyMethodsInstances2 {
private String girlName;
public void setName(String temp){
    girlName=temp;
}
public String getName(){
    return girlName;
}
public void saying(){
    System.out.println("Your first gf was %s", getName());
}
}

public class ManyMethodsInstances2 {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    UsingManyMethodsInstances2 manyMethodsInstances2Object = new UsingManyMethodsInstances2();
    System.out.println("Enter name of first gf here: ");
    String temp = input.nextLine();
    manyMethodsInstances2Object.setName(temp);
    manyMethodsInstances2Object.saying();
}

}
```

Comment: `println` only takes one argument as far as I am aware. Change the code to `"Your first gf was %s" + getName());`.

Comment: Should be `System.out.println("Your first gf was " + getName());` - without the %s

Comment: You could also use `System.out.println(String.format("Your first gf was %s", getName()));`

Comment: @Rex it is asking The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're not using the code you've provided to or by us. Because I ran it and it works as expected. Make sure that you have compiled your changes before running it again and let us know if it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
System.out.println("Your first gf was %s", getName());
```

to

```
System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s", getName());
```

println only takes object or string.

Comment: The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String) ...it is asking Changr return type of getName.....() to Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `System.out.println()` only takes one argument. The string should concatenate with the variable. Your `saying()` method should be like:

```
public void saying(){
    System.out.println("Your first gf was " + getName());
}
```

If you really want to use placeholders, you can use `System.out.printf()`:

```
public void saying(){
    System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s", getName());
}
```

Or you can use `String.format()` inside `println()` just as well:

```
public void saying(){
    System.out.println(String.format("Your first gf was {0}", getName()));
}
```

Comment: @Memphys............public void saying(){
    System.out.println("Your first gf was " + getName());
} ...its working..:)..thankyou..:)

Comment: Well, it wasn't me ;) you can upvote my answer if it was useful for you tho.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrongly the method to print the concatenated msg...

you can either do:

```
System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s", getName());
```

or

```
System.out.println(String.format("Your first gf was %s", getName()));
```

but

```
`System.out.println("Your first gf was %s", getName());`
```

is not correct since that method requires **only 1** parameter..

Comment: if is not working then you have another error in the code that you didnt show us.....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpa The problem he means (see the other comments under the other question) is related to his currently used language level.